# Better approach to calling controller from Tiles?

Tags: spring, controller, tiles

I am using Tiles 2 in a new Spring MVC 3 app.
This is my template

```
  <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/layout.jsp"  >
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="userInfo" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

and my page

```
<definition name="engageStep1View" extends="baseLayout"  >
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/private/engageStep1.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="userInfo" value="/layout/userInfo" />
</definition>
```

I added to the tiles.xml definition the next line

```
<definition name="userInfoView" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/userInfo.jsp"   />
```

There is a better idea to enagageStep1 call to the controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/layout/userInfo")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(ModelMap model) {

        ......
        MemberPrincipal memberPrincipal = (MemberPrincipal)authentication.getPrincipal();

        model.put("userName", memberPrincipal.getUserName());

        return new ModelAndView("userInfoView", "model", model);
    }
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Update: There is a better idea to **userInfo** call to the controller:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your userInfo controller method is providing information that could apply to your whole app/site.  For this kind of info, you could use a spring interceptor to populate the info required in to the current attribute context.  Then the userInfoView can just use this info as required, without having to reference userInfo controller method.

Another similar approach is to user a tiles view preparer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you are righ userInfo is used for several pages and isplay information for the session user.
 I'll try your recomendations